# How do you convert a single entity list into a string python

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to convert a tuple:

```
('Cobra',)
```

to a string, which when printed yields:

```
Cobra
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your expected output is. Is it `'Cobra'` or `"('Cobra')"` or something else? (`('Cobra')` evaluates to just `'Cobra'`)

Comment: You may want to explain what you are up to. Also `('Cobra')=='Cobra'` will return `True`

Comment: and `('Cobra',)` is a tuple

Comment: Unclear, but how about `tupl[0]` where `tupl` is the input?

Comment: You should avoid `list` as a variable name because it shadows the builtin

Comment: `print( ('Cobra',)[0] )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Assuming you have a list of tuples
    sample = [('cobra',),('Cat',),('Dog',),('hello',),('Cobra',)]

#For each tuple in the list, Get the first element of each tuple
    x = [i[0] for i in sample]
```